# How to change excluded urls in Mozilla SDK page-mod dynamically

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla

How do I change the value of 'exclude' in the Mozilla SDK's page-mod and use the new value at runtime? In my scenario, when a user chooses to exclude the page from my addon, I refresh the 'pages' array in the simple-storage. I want to immediately exclude this page from processing by somehow restarting the page-mod with the new settings. At the moment, when I reload the excluded tab, my script is still working on the page.

The only thing that works at the moment is just the static array declaration: ['*.example.org'].

```
var  excludedUrls = require("sdk/simple-storage").storage.pages; // doesn't 
//work.
//When exclude is set to this var I get:  "Message: RequirementError: 
//If set, the `exclude` option must always contain at  least one rule as a 
//string, regular expression, or an array of strings and regular expressions."
// excludedUrls does contain an array of stings!

var pm = require("sdk/page-mod").PageMod({
include: ['*'],
//Error when set to: excludedUrls OR require("sdk/simple-storage").storage.pages 
exclude: ['*.example.org'],  
contentScriptWhen: "ready",
attachTo: ["existing", "top"],
contentScriptFile: [data.url("script.js")]    
});
```

Page-mode entry in MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got that error when I inadvertently was adding null values to storage. Log the value of `excludedUrls` to make sure it's only strings.

As for `exclude`, you can do `pm.include = someArray` or `pm.include.add(someString)`/`pm.include.remove(someString)` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod#destroy%28%29)). Have you tried the same thing with `exclude`? If so, you should [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=guided#h=dupes|Add-on%20SDK|General) to tell them to add it to the documentation.